# outputStream.println() - not printing to .log file?? I can't see why

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to print a time entry to a log file and it will not output. I have used almost the same exact code to log messages and it worked fine. Can anyone see something I'm not seeing? The testing print lines all print, and no errors occur. Thanks for your help...

```
private static String logTime(long time, String operation)
  {
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    String logFile = "time.log";

    System.out.println("Writing output");
    try{
    System.out.println("Writing output2");
      outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(logFile, true));


    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("File not found by logTime.");
    }
    System.out.println("Writing output3");

    outputStream.println(operation); //operation + " : " + Long.toString(time) + "Mills"
    outputStream.close();

    return "";
  }
```

Comment: exactly which statements are printed?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code snippet you have posted.

Comment: Here is something odd, when I delete the time.log file from the directory, the FileNotFoundException does not get thrown. I was expecting it to fail when outputStream was instanciated and it didn't...

Comment: @KirkB You never mentioned you were getting an exception; that's kind of an important piece of information.

Comment: Brian, you were correct. I went into the project folder (outside the src/package) and it had created a time.log file there and was outputting there. I was expecting it to use the file I created in the package.

Comment: @Brian, I was not getting any exceptions. Even when I deleted the file I thought should be getting written to. That prompted me to look around the project a bit and found the other file I didn't know about. I agree with your statement, if I was getting any, I would certainly have mentioned that...

Comment: @KirkB Ah, ok. Sorry, misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time to look and comment. It is much appreciated. A great community here!

Answer (score 1):

In your code your use the constructor without automatic line flushing.

`PrintWriter(OutputStream out)` Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, from an existing OutputStream.

You should therefore use `outputStream.flush()` or use the constructor with automatic line flushing:

`PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)`.

For details see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: close() first flush()es.

Comment: @jackrabbit you're right `close()` first calls `flush()`. But I think is a good habit to `flush()` every time you write to a Stream.

Comment: That is certainly a safe route, but flush "commits" what you wrote (whatever commit means for that stream). Doing that every time can incur quite a performance penalty.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But IMHO it is the responsibility of the client to decide (a) when to write something and (b) when to commit it. On the other side `PrintWriter` do not call `flush()` before `close()`. It only calls `abstract public void close();` of the abstract class `java.io.Writer`. How do you know (later, if you or someone changes the Writer in your application) if the `Writer` has properly implemented the contract which requires to flush before close?

Comment: You can not automatically protect against classes that do not implement their contract properly. Being a decorator, `PrintWriter` can only trust the contract of its delegate. If you're worried about something subtle like this breaking, write an automated test for it.

Comment: If you don't want to `flush()` its up to you. I won't explain why I recommend our developers to follow this habit and allways `flush()` after write. We simply consider it a good habit aka best practices.